# Oracle simple count(*) SQL query takes "forever"

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, count

I'm encountering an "issue" (at least a strange/slow behavior) with a new installation of Oracle 12c on Windows Server 2019, with this query which takes at least 5 minutes to complete:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS.ALL_VIEWS;
```

Why does it take so much time?
What am I missing?

Oracle 12c is running on Win2019 (in a VMWare VM) on a SSD. The VM has 5 GB ram. It's probably not enough for a "real" database, but mine contains a default generic database (no user data) because I only need to make a quick test for a customer.

Thank you.

Comment: How is this preventing you from performing the actual test?

Comment: You're right, it does not prevent me from performing it. But since we are using this view, I was wondering why some queries run so slowly (because I guess that since it has happened to me on a new Oracle configuration without any user data, it might happen at some customer's places too)

Comment: Have you gathered dictionary stats and fixed object stats (`dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats` and `dbms_stats.gather_fixed_object_stats`)?  It sounds like you're getting bad query plans so making sure the optimizer has the right stats would be step 1.

Comment: @Justin Cave Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it does not improve this query execution time.

Comment: Out of curiousity, does anything change if you drop dictionary and fixed object stats (`dbms_stats.delete_dictionary_stats` and `dbms_stats.delete_fixed_object_stats`)?

Comment: @Justin Cave Something might have changed (I have not completely checked the execution plans), but the execution time remains very slow for the SYSTEM user (actually I canceled the query), but still not for SYS AS SYSDBA (exec time remains "stable", around 1 second). Out of ideas, I have tried to force the RBO, /*+RULE */ hint, but the query execution is still extremely slow (except for the SYS user of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS.ALL_VIEWS;
```

Is not a simple query. `ALL_VIEWS` is a very complicated view, it has many joins requiring special logic to determine what the calling user is actually allowed to see.

You can use `all_views` to see the logic behind `all_views`, this is how it looks on 19c.

```
select OWNER, VIEW_NAME, TEXT_LENGTH, TEXT, TEXT_VC,TYPE_TEXT_LENGTH, TYPE_TEXT,
       OID_TEXT_LENGTH, OID_TEXT, VIEW_TYPE_OWNER, VIEW_TYPE, SUPERVIEW_NAME,
       EDITIONING_VIEW, READ_ONLY,  CONTAINER_DATA, BEQUEATH,
       ORIGIN_CON_ID, DEFAULT_COLLATION, CONTAINERS_DEFAULT, CONTAINER_MAP,
       EXTENDED_DATA_LINK, EXTENDED_DATA_LINK_MAP, HAS_SENSITIVE_COLUMN
from int$dba_views
where (OWNER = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER')
       or OBJ_ID(OWNER, VIEW_NAME, 4, OBJECT_ID) in
            (select oa.obj#
             from sys.objauth$ oa
             where oa.grantee# in ( select kzsrorol
                                         from x$kzsro
                                  )
            )
        or /* user has system privileges */
           /* 4 is the type# for Views. See kgl.h for more info */
          exists (select null from v$enabledprivs
                  where priv_number in (-45 /* LOCK ANY TABLE */,
                                        -47 /* SELECT ANY TABLE */,
                                        -397/* READ ANY TABLE */,
                                        -48 /* INSERT ANY TABLE */,
                                        -49 /* UPDATE ANY TABLE */,
                                        -50 /* DELETE ANY TABLE */)
                  )
      )
```

Simple enough? Well, `int$dba_views` is actually a view itself, so lets go deeper, this view is defined by

```
select u.name, u.user#, o.name, o.obj#, o.type#, v.textlength, v.text,
       getlong(1, v.rowid),
       t.typetextlength, t.typetext,
       t.oidtextlength, t.oidtext, t.typeowner, t.typename,
       decode(bitand(v.property, 134217728), 134217728,
              (select sv.name from superobj$ h, sys."_CURRENT_EDITION_OBJ" sv
              where h.subobj# = o.obj# and h.superobj# = sv.obj#), null),
       decode(bitand(v.property, 32), 32, 'Y', 'N'),
       decode(bitand(v.property, 16384), 16384, 'Y', 'N'),

       decode(bitand(v.property/4294967296, 134217728), 134217728, 'Y', 'N'),
       decode(bitand(o.flags,8),8,'CURRENT_USER','DEFINER'),
       case when bitand(o.flags, (65536+131072+4294967296))>0 then 1 else 0 end,
       to_number(sys_context('USERENV', 'CON_ID')),
       nls_collation_name(nvl(o.dflcollid, 16382)),
       -- CONTAINERS_DEFAULT
       decode(bitand(v.property, power(2,72)), power(2,72), 'YES', 'NO'),
       -- CONTAINER_MAP
       decode(bitand(v.property, power(2,80)), power(2,80), 'YES', 'NO'),
       -- EXTENDED_DATA_LINK
       decode(bitand(v.property, power(2,52)), power(2,52), 'YES', 'NO'),
       -- EXTENDED_DATA_LINK_MAP
       decode(bitand(v.property, power(2,79)), power(2,79), 'YES', 'NO'),
       -- HAS_SENSITIVE_COLUMN
       decode(bitand(v.property, power(2,89)), power(2,89), 'YES', 'NO')
from sys."_CURRENT_EDITION_OBJ" o, sys.view$ v, sys.user$ u, sys.typed_view$ t
where o.obj# = v.obj#
  and o.obj# = t.obj#(+)
  and o.owner# = u.user#
```

Guess what, `sys."_CURRENT_EDITION_OBJ"` is also a view which has complex filters. I won't keep pasting as you can follow the trail on your own 12c installation (and it will likely be slightly different).

But the important thing to note here is that actual usage of `ALL_VIEWS` is fast when you are looking up a view by name, it is not fast to compute every single view that you might be able to use (and that is reasonable as it's not something you would ever need to do in a hurry).

If you want to use `ALL_VIEWS` in some sort of benchmark then you could materialize it into a table and count that instead.

```
create table all_views_mat as select * from all_views;

select count(*) from all_views_mat;
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. Just for the record, the Oracle 12c ODBC driver (at least on Windows, x64) seems to use this view when a program asks the list of schemas (with the SQLTables() ODBC API); and it takes a very long time. Maybe it's better with other versions of the ODBC driver. I will try.

Comment: The Oracle ODBC Driver 19c seem to s**k as much as the 12c when it has to retrieve the list of schemas from the database with SQLTables(). I guess that both must use the same query (did not investigate). Fortunately there are other ways to retrieve this list.

Comment: Just for fun: retrieving the list of schema with the Oracle ODBC Driver took almost 40 minutes! (loool). I believe that Oracle really should do something about that. Well, maybe I'm the only one retrieving the list of schema in the world from an Oracle database, so no one has ever reported this problem.

Comment: Rather than running `SQLTables()`, use the SQL statement `select username from all_users`. That said, this sort of query is the sort of thing a developer would be running manually when they are trying to figure out the data model, using ODBC for this is not typical, you would use something like 'SQL Developer' or 'toad' (or a command line alternative). I tried to replicate what you were doing but it seems `SQLTables` isn't implemented easily by the .net ODBC class (I'm using powershell) so I'd have to write some "proper" code to run it - I would rather just fire up SQL Developer etc.

Comment: If you want to raise the performance issue of SQLTables() to Oracle then you will need to log it with them directly. Either as a support case (support.oracle.com) which requires a support contract, or maybe unofficially through their community pages (maybe https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/categories/database-ideas-ideas ).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The query you suggested to retrieve schemas is exactly the one I had chosen to use too.

Answer (score 2):

Running the same query on an Oracle instance at my company which is 1 TB in size, executes in less than a second.

#### Executing as SYS AS SYSDBA

```
set pages 50
set lines 230
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS.ALL_VIEWS;
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL;
```

Results in:

> ```
> Session altered.
>
> CURRENT_DATE         
> ---------------------
> 2021-11-05 15:00:26  
> 1 row selected.
>
>   COUNT(*)
> ----------
>       6785
> 1 row selected.
>
> CURRENT_DATE         
> ---------------------
> 2021-11-05 15:00:26  
> 1 row selected.
> ```

As pointed out in other answers, it can be related to the complexity of the view you are querying, but I wouldn't bet all my money on that.

#### Other Things to Consider

The query can be related to the permissions that you have. Have you tried running the query as `SYS as SYSDBA`?

Then having an Oracle database instance with only 5 GB and a database that is 10 GB in size, may impact performance. Think: Data not yet in cache.

Another issue has to do with the memory configuration of your Oracle instance. Are you running **Automatic Memory Management** (AMM) where you configure the `MEMORY_MAX_TARGET`and `MEMORY_TARGET` parameters or **Automatic Shared Memory Management** (ASMM) where you configure the `sga_target` and `sga_max_size` parameters? Have you set the values to something higher than 1 GB so that the Oracle database instance can benefit from having the ability to cache some of the database objects (data) to RAM?

What happens if you run the query a second time? Do you have the same bad performance? Think: Database (data) caching.

If you local system is running other virtual machines, then turn them off and try it again. Does it run faster?

Are you running any other memory or CPU intensive applications on the same desktop/server? Turn them off.

Anti-Virus software? Turn if off or follow the recommendation from Oracle to exclude certain files / directories from being scanned.

If you follow up with a couple of these recommendations, then you should observer a speed up in performance when querying the simple view.

Oh, by the way, my Oracle instance is 1 TB in size and has the `SGA_TARGET` set to `84 GB`. Memory is essential for database performance.

#### Running Query as SYSTEM

> ```
> Session altered.
>
> CURRENT_DATE         
> ---------------------
> 2021-11-10 12:46:24  
> 1 row selected.
>
>   COUNT(*)
> ----------
>       6785
> 1 row selected.
>
> CURRENT_DATE         
> ---------------------
> 2021-11-10 12:46:25  
> 1 row selected.
> ```

#### Running Query as Non-Privileged User

I create an unprivileged user named `UNPRIV_USER` with absolutely no privileges except for `GRANT CONNECT ...` and `GRANT CREATE SESSION ...` and then re-ran the same statement against the huge 1TB Oracle database instance and here are the results:

> ```
> Session altered.
>
> CURRENT_DATE         
> ---------------------
> 2021-11-10 12:56:40  
> 1 row selected.
>
>   COUNT(*)
> ----------
>       1729
> 1 row selected.
>
> CURRENT_DATE         
> ---------------------
> 2021-11-10 12:56:40  
> 1 row selected.
> ```

So while the unprivileged user doesn't have access to certain VIEWS, this doesn't have an impact on the duration of the query executing.

#### Conclusion

The permissions / privileges can probably have an affect on the execution time of the simple query, but in my environment it doesn't seem to have that much of an impact. (+/- 1 second)

I'd start looking at your virtualization and or instance-specific configuration settings.

E.g. my instance is running on dedicated hardware (16 cores @ 2.8 GHz, 768 GB RAM, 84 GB SGA for the mentioned instance).

#### Desktop OS vs. Server OS

Desktop OS and server OS prioritise things differently. A desktop OS will prioritise the foreground application, where a server OS will be normally configured to prioritise the background application (servcies).

On a Windows system follow these quick steps to configure your system to prioritise background applications:

> To increase performance for background service like SQL Server / Oracle host instances, follow these steps:
>
> - Click **Start**, click **Control Panel**, and then click **System**.
>   - *Alternatively: Hit the Windows Key and type **sysdm.cpl** and then **ENTER**. This should bring up the System Control Panel.*
> - Click the **Advanced** tab, and then click **Settings** under **Performance**.
> - Click the **Advanced** tab, click **Background services**, and then click **OK twice**.

This should result in better performance for the Oracle service on a Windows OS.

Comment: using SYSTIMESTAMP, my 12c DB has 7122 views. Query took 0.031 seconds. My 19c DB has 12,461 views. Query took 0.156. 19C DB has less RAM by more than half. But I didn't try running it through ODBC, to see how much that added to the time.

Comment: @John K. N.: Thank you for the suggestions. and you were right: running this query as SYS/SYSDBA is very fast (less than one second). As you probably guessed I'm not an Oracle expert, so can you explain why it is so slow when I run the same query as SYSTEM please? Is it related to permissions? SYSTEM must have a lot permissions I suppose, so what will happen with "regular" users. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll get back to you with results from my environment. I'll run the query with `SYSTEM` and a generic user to find out how the accounts vary. It does have to do with the complexity of the view as already pointed out, but the query duration might also be impacted by the configuration of your Oracle database instance.

Comment: @JohnK.N. I'm eager to know your results :)

Comment: ok. Thank you very much. I have increased RAM for my VM and the SGA is set to 2.5 GB (which does not seem so bad for my tiny database: the size used by the "files" for my DB is 4GB). Unfortunately it doesn't change the terrible times I get. Anyway, thanks a lot for taking the time to perform the tests.

Comment: You might also want to consider that a Windows desktop is primarily configured to optimise foreground applications. Switching this to background applications (services) can improve the performance of "server" applications.

Comment: I've added an additional point that came to mind while thinking about the differences in execution time.

Comment: In my case the OS is windows server (2019), and it is already configured to "optimize background applications".